# Polybase on ADLS Gen2 - CSV file as source failing with 'HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer' error

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, polybase, azure-data-lake-gen2

This is my first time using Polybase and I'm trying to load a sample CSV file (with first record as header) from **ADLS Gen2** to Synapse. 
I've already created a Master Key before so I didn't create it again. The remaining steps I'm implemented are as follows:

```
-- Step 1

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL access_cred
WITH
    IDENTITY = 'my_name',
    SECRET = '12345678910****==';

-- Step 2

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE CreditCards
WITH
(
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION = 'abfss://container01@freesandbox.dfs.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = access_cred
);

-- Step 3

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT CC_FileFormat
WITH
(
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS
    (
        FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
        FIRST_ROW = 2,
        USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = FALSE
    )
);

--Step 4

CREATE SCHEMA ext;
CREATE SCHEMA cc;

--Step 5: Create External Table

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext.creditcards (
    Card_Type_Full_Name varchar(50),
    Issuing_Bank varchar(50),
    Card_Number varchar(50),
    Card_Holder_Name varchar(50),
    CVV_CVV2 varchar(50),
    Issue_Date varchar(50),
    Expiry_Date varchar(50),
    Billing_Date varchar(50),
    Card_PIN varchar(50),
    Credit_Limit varchar(50)
)
WITH (LOCATION='/CreditCards/', --I've a folder 'CreditCards' inside which the 'Creditcards.csv` file sits
    DATA_SOURCE = CreditCards,  
    FILE_FORMAT = CC_FileFormat,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
);


--Step 6

CREATE TABLE cc.creditcards
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS
SELECT * FROM ext.creditcards
OPTION (LABEL = 'CTAS : Load cc.creditcards');
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried going through multiple posts over internet but nothing really addresses the issue I'm facing. I get the below error when trying to do `SELECT * from <external_table>`. (This is also the error I get in Step 6 as I'm CTAS command to load my final table.)

```
Msg 107090, Level 16, State 1, Line 74
HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I don't understand what else is missing. I've given access permissions on the Container level as well.
Can someone please help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved:** Turns out, this error was being caused due to file encoding. The source flatfile I placed on ADLS G2 was in ANSI and I just had to re-upload it by converting it to UTF8. After that it worked perfectly.

Found this tip in a post on Microsoft forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6a431c73-4575-4729-b7b5-9767e2a16c0e/external-table-error?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse

For converting ANSI flatfile to UTF8 (using Notepad): https://superuser.com/a/911373