# Azure Data Factory, MalformedInputException on a copy data activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-synapse

My copy data activity gets data in .snappy.parquet format (from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2) and brings it to Azure Synapse Analytics.

I keep receiving this:

*Copy Command operation failed with error 'HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: MalformedInputException: Input length = 1'*

I use a pre-copy script that has this structure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[SCHEMA].[TABLE]') IS NOT NULL BEGIN     
DROP TABLE [SCHEMA].[TABLE] END 
CREATE TABLE [SCHEMA].[TABLE] (  [FIELD]  VARCHAR(4386)   ,[FIELD]  DECIMAL(18,8), ...) 
WITH ( 
DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN, 
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX 
)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: are you sure all of your varchar() fields require length less than 128? Could be that one of them needs upto 5708.         VARCHAR(size) A VARIABLE length string (can contain letters, numbers, and special characters). The size parameter specifies the maximum column length in characters - can be from 0 to 65535

Comment: yeah but when reading it into your table you need to have that field as varchar(5800) for example or you could go with text(size) as well.

Comment: I meant when constructing your table schema (instead of reading)^^

Comment: Mostly this error might be caused due to encoding. Change the file encoding to UTF 8. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346931/polybase-on-adls-gen2-csv-file-as-source-failing-with-hdfsbridgerecordreade)